# Fingerprint at pipeline Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fingerprinting

How can I add fingerprint to artefact at pipeline Jenkins job?
I added the needed plugins and used the parameters as described at the [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven).

```
withMaven(options: [artifactsPublisher(disabled: false), dependenciesFingerprintPublisher(disabled: false)])
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. 
The fingerprint is done by a special command

```
step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
```

It is recommended to do it in a dedicated step, this is what I did:

```
stage('arch') {
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
}
```

More details can be found [here](http://rodrigozrusso.com/2016/11/09/jenkins-fingerprinting.html)